# Hide image when same button pushed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I know how to show an image when a button is pressed. But how do you "hide" the image again once the button is pressed a second time? Here is all I have so far...

```
-(IBAction)Light
{
    LightLCD.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: This is not a question about Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
-(IBAction)Light
{
    LightLCD.hidden = !LightLCD.hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
- (IBAction)Light
{
    LightLCD.hidden = !LightLCD.hidden;
}
```

This way you can toggle the visibility of the imageView.